# Запись в файл на С++ результатов запроса к postgres базе

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, файлы, c++

Производится чтение из базы даннных слов и имен файлов (которые содержат эти слова) и запись их в текстовый файл в следующем формате: файл состоит из 2 колонок, разделенных пробелом, первая колонка - это слова из файлов, вторая колонка - это имена файлов. Хочу спросить производит ли следующая программа данные действия:

```
#include <iostream>

//using namespace std;

#include <stdio.h>
#include "libpq-fe.h"
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdlib.h>

int     main() {
    PGconn          *conn;
    PGresult        *res;
    int             rec_count;
    int             row;
    int             col;
    FILE            *stream;

    conn = PQconnectdb("hostaddr=192.168.1.8 port=5432 connect_timeout=10 dbname=NexentaSearch user=postgres password=valter89");
    if (PQstatus(conn) == CONNECTION_BAD) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Connection to database failed: %s\n",PQerrorMessage(conn));
     puts("No connection");
        exit(0);
    }

    res = PQexec(conn, "SELECT a.value, c.value FROM therms a INNER JOIN therms_occurs b ON b.therm_id = a.id INNER JOIN fs_entries c ON b.file_id = c.id ORDER BY a.value, c.value");

    if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_TUPLES_OK) {
        printf("We didn't get the data");
        exit(0);
    }

    rec_count = PQntuples(res);

    printf("We got %d records.\n", rec_count);
    puts("==========================");

    stream=fopen("/usr/indexes.txt", "w");
    for (row=0; row<rec_count; row++) {
        for (col=0; col<2; col++) {
            fprintf(stream, "%s ", PQgetvalue(res, row, col));
            if ((col=1) && (row < rec_count-1))
            {
                fprintf(stream, "\n");
            }
        }
    }

    puts("==========================");
    PQclear(res);
    PQfinish(conn);
    fclose(stream);
    return 0;
}
```

Конкретно интересует правильность 2-х операторов `fprintf`: вернее для первого соответствие поставленному результату, а для второго - допустимость отсутствия фактических аргументов.

Comment: > Хочу спросить производит ли следующая программа данные действия:

А вы не спрашивайте, вы проверьте самостоятельно. Или вы хотите, чтобы кто-то собрал и отладил код за вас?

Comment: @klopp моя проблема меньше: будет ли цикл

  for (row=0; row<rec_count; row++) {
   for (col=0; col<2; col++) {
    fprintf(stream, "%s ", PQgetvalue(res, row, col));
    if ((col=1) && (row < rec_count-1))
    {
     fprintf(stream, "\n);
    }
   }
  }
записывать в файл в 2 колонки через пробел результаты запроса. Меня просто смутило, что в качестве аргумента передается PQgetvalue(res, row, col) и спрашиваю я: будет ли по идее работать, но никак не прошу ее запускать и проверять (у меня пока нет возможности проверить, поскольку база не заполнена).

Comment: Запустите и узнаете. Отладчиком пройдитесь и увидите всё своими глазами.

Comment: >у меня пока нет возможности проверить, поскольку база не заполнена

Значит, нужно заполнить базу какими-то тестовыми данными. Ну что за детский сад, чесслово.

Comment: @ivan89, а почему бы попроще не написать и не гадать?

    for (row=0; row<rec_count; row++) {
      fprintf(stream, "%s ", PQgetvalue(res, row, 0));
      fprintf(stream, "%s\n", PQgetvalue(res, row, 1));
    }

Просто, коротко и понятно, что вывод в 2 колонки.